# Angular js wait for translate to finish rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I put https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak directive to my body element on the page and every element witch has angular in it , but it looks like it doesnt work on angular-js translate. I see translate variables on the page and after one second they are translated.Is there something to fix this?

Comment: which translate framework do you use ?

Comment: @KonstantinKrass https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate

Comment: i do use it with like 100 keys / view and dont have this side effect. Do you load the messages before angular ? or do you load them async?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because angular-translate is executed **after** angular itself is ready. What you need is the `translate-cloak` directive. [http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.directive:translateCloak](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.directive%3atranslateCloak) in combination with the according method on `$translate` service http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate#methods_cloakclassname

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using the `translate-cloak` and the `ng-clock` as attributes on a `<div class="header"` but it does not work, I still see the keys flickering. Cannot figure out what to do with the documentation. Could you add a minimal piece of code or clarify ? Thanks.